# Jackrabbit Delphi bindings?

Tags: delphi, jackrabbit

I'm looking for a way to use the content repository of Apache Jackrabbit from Delphi.
I've googled about this but to no avail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) supports [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), which could be used to access the content from Delphi clients.

The [documentation indicates](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/standalone-server.html#StandaloneServer-WebDAVaccess) that full remote JCR access is possible over WebDAV using the Jackrabbit Standalone Server:

> The repository also exposes an alternative WebDAV access point at
>   http://localhost:8080/server/ for more fine-grained content access.
>   This access point implements a number of advanced WebDAV features that
>   are not normally seen in plain file-based WebDAV servers. You will
>   need a feature-rich WebDAV or HTTP client to access the full power of
>   this interface. **With the Jackrabbit spi2dav component you can even get
>   full remote JCR access over the WebDAV features and some custom
>   extensions available through this access point**.

The page http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-web-application.html lists more options, using the Jackrabbit Web Application (RepositoryAccessServlet, JCRWebdavServerServlet and others)

Comment: Yes, in fact I've already done some test, accessing jackrabbit datastore from delphi through WebDAV.
But I would like to use the full Jackrabbit APIs to access versioning, metadata, attributes etc.

Comment: See my update, the documentation indicates that full remote JCR access is possible over WebDAV

Comment: Thank you very much: I'll investigate it.